# Как в PyQt5 изменить GUI через сторонний поток?

Tags: python, qt5, python-3.x

Вот часть программы

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import PyQt5.QtWidgets
import PyQt5.QtCore
import sys
import time

class MyThread(PyQt5.QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        PyQt5.QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(60)
        # ?

class MyTabWidget(PyQt5.QtWidgets.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        PyQt5.QtWidgets.QTabWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.widget = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.en = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.ru = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.ipa = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.add = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QPushButton("add")
        self.form = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.widget)
        self.form.addRow("&En", self.en)
        self.form.addRow("&Ru", self.ru)
        self.form.addRow("&IPA", self.ipa)
        self.form.addRow(self.add)
        self.widget2 = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.repeat = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QPushButton("repeat")
        self.form2 = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.widget2)
        self.form2.addRow(self.repeat)
        self.addTab(self.widget, "add")
        self.addTab(self.widget2, "repeat")
        self.th = MyThread()
        self.th.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tab = MyTabWidget()
    tab.show()
    app = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

результатом которого является:

[image]

Как мне, в запущенном потоке `th`, изменить надпись `repeat` на `***repeat`?

[image]

В четвертой версии PyQt знаю данные потока GUI изменялись через сигнал. Но в 5-ой создание сигнала немного по другому. Там как-то с `PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal` надо мудрить. Вот здесь я и запутался.

Comment: можно вызвать `postEvent()` в MyThread потоке и поменять заголовок в соответствующем обработчике событий в GUI потоке. Вот [пример многопоточного кода для Gtk Tree на Питоне](http://askubuntu.com/a/183315/3712) -- посмотри как `idle_add()` (аналог `postEvent()`), `timeout_add()` (аналог `QTimer()`) функции используются.

Answer (score 1):

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import threading, time


class Wind(QtGui.QWidget):
    Signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(list)

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.Signal.connect(lambda s: self.resize(s[0], s[1]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
    QApp = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Wind()
    w.show()

    # отдельный поток
    def resize():
        for i in range(1000):
            w.Signal.emit([i, i])  # изменяем размер из другого потока
            time.sleep(0.1)
    threading.Thread(target=resize).start()

    QApp.exec()
```

Comment: Пример какой то неполный